# Find latest copy of same file in folder structure

Tags: find, path, search

I need to get the path of foo.txt in a folder structure. 
There are multiple foo.txt files in this structure but I need an automated to find the latest.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -iname foo.txt -exec ls -t "{}" \+ | head -n 1
```

Comment: I prefer using xargs syntax and don't use ls on scripting but good idea

Comment: works awesome with one caveats. If there is only one hit, this returns "Contents." Since i'm piping the path to open the file returning the path would be preferred.

Comment: @KevinSchneider Can you supply with full output the case with one hit of `find . -iname foo.txt -exec ls -t "{}" \+` ?

Comment: `Kevins-MacBook-Pro:production schneik$ find . -iname foo.txt -exec ls -t "{}" \+ | head -n 1`  
`Contents`  
`Kevins-MacBook-Pro:production schneik$`

Comment: hmmm spaces not creating line breaks on my code blocks

Comment: @KevinSchneider Please show command output without `| head ...`

Answer (score 2):

This is a case for [zsh's glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) if I ever saw one.

```
cat **/foo.txt(om[1])
```

- `om` sorts files by increasing age (i.e. by modification time, newest first).
- `[1]` selects only the first match.

If you're invoking this from another shell and want to use the file name, you can use

```
latest_foo=$(zsh -c 'print -r -- **/foo.txt(om[1])')
```

but you might as well write your whole script in zsh.

Answer (score 1):

```
 find . -iname foo.txt -printf '%CYmd %p%f' | sort -n -t ' ' -k 2 | head -n 1
```

Comment: terminal (OS X) throws an error on -printf ?

Comment: Ham, according to the OS X man, printf is not available